# Redux saga failed in production

Tags: react-redux, redux-saga, production-environment, production, http-status-code-304

I've been trying to tackle this problem more than 2 weeks now. Everything works fine in `development` mode. But not in `production` mode. The example below are shown using `Redux Saga` environment (**I'm still new in redux saga**). But I've tried re-do it using `Context API`. Unfortunately the problem still persists. (**below are the images showing successful process in development mode & unsuccessful process in production mode**)

- **successful** in `development` mode
  [image]
- **unsuccessful** in `production` mode
  [image]

My guess it could be something to do with status code `304 Not Modified`. Since the data I tried to fetch not changing, thus it will use cached data in browser. But I don't know how to setup my server so that I can handle this issue. I have read a bunch of online threads. But none were able to resolve my issue.

You may have a look at my code right now. **Bear in mind that everything works just fine in development mode**. From the images above you can see that I don't have problem logging in. Just fetching & getting data to be displayed in dashboard got error.

- `client/src/redux/actions/Dashboard.js` (**Action**)

```js
import { SET_ISDASHBOARD, SET_LOADING, SET_ERROR } from '../sagas/types'

// Set Loading
export const setLoading = (status) => ({ 
  type: SET_LOADING, 
  payload: status 
})

// Set Error
export const setError = (error) => ({ 
  type: SET_ERROR, 
  payload: { error: error.status, message: error.message } 
})

// Dashboard
export const isDashboard = () => ({
  type: SET_ISDASHBOARD
})
```

- `client/src/redux/reducers/Dashboard.jd` (**Reducer**)

```js
import { SET_ERROR, SET_LOADING, SET_ISDASHBOARD, SET_DASHBOARD } from '../sagas/types'

const initialState = {
  user: {
    id: '',
    name: '',
    email: ''
  },
  loading: false,
  error: false,
  message: ''
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case SET_ISDASHBOARD:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      }
    case SET_DASHBOARD:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: {
          ...state.user,
          id: action.payload.id,
          email: action.payload.email,
          name: action.payload.name
        }
      }
    case SET_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.payload.status,
        message: action.payload.message
      }
    case SET_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: action.payload
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default reducer
```

- `client/src/redux/sagas/handlers/dashboard.js` (**Saga handlers**)

```js
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { requestGetDashboard } from '../requests/dashboard'
import { SET_LOADING, SET_ERROR, SET_DASHBOARD } from '../types'

export function* handleGetDashboard(action) {
  try {
    const response = yield call(requestGetDashboard)
    const result = response.data.data
    console.log(response); console.log(result)
    // dispatch set dashboard
    yield put({ type: SET_DASHBOARD, payload: { id: result.id, email: result.email, name: result.name } })
  } catch(error) {
    // console.log(error); console.log(error.response)
    const result = error.response.data
    const payload = {
      status: true,
      message: result.error
    }

    // dispatch setError
    yield put({ type: SET_ERROR, payload: payload })
  }

  // loading to false
  yield put({ type: SET_LOADING, payload: false })
}
```

- `client/src/redux/sagas/requests/dashboard.js` (**Saga requests**)

```js
import axios from 'axios'

/** get dashboard */
export const requestGetDashboard = () => { 
  return axios.get(
    '/api/v1/dashboard', 
    {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('uid')}`
      }
    }
  )
}
```

- `client/src/redux/sagas/rootSaga.js` (**Root Saga**)

```js
import { 
  SET_ISLOGIN, SET_ISLOGOUT, SET_ISAUTH,
  SET_ISDASHBOARD, 
} from './types'
import { takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { handleClientAuth, handlePostLogin, handlePostLogout } from './handlers/auth'
import { handleGetDashboard } from './handlers/dashboard'

export function* watcherSaga() {
  // auth
  yield takeLatest(SET_ISLOGIN, handlePostLogin)
  yield takeLatest(SET_ISLOGOUT, handlePostLogout)
  yield takeLatest(SET_ISAUTH, handleClientAuth)
  // dashboard
  yield takeLatest(SET_ISDASHBOARD, handleGetDashboard)
}
```

- `client/src/redux/sagas/types.js` (**Types**)

```js
/** for AUTH */
export const SET_ISLOGIN = 'SET_ISLOGIN'
export const SET_ISLOGOUT = 'SET_ISLOGOUT'
export const SET_ISAUTH = 'SET_ISAUTH'
export const SET_AUTH = 'SET_AUTH'
export const SET_LOADING = 'SET_LOADING'
export const SET_ERROR = 'SET_ERROR'

/** for DASHBOARD */
export const SET_ISDASHBOARD = 'SET_ISDASHBOARD'
export const SET_DASHBOARD = 'SET_DASHBOARD'
```

Please point me to any directions that could help get closer insight to this problem.

Comment: I don’t know why the API request itself would be failing in production (possibly due to authentication?) but the particular error that you are getting “cannot read property data of undefined” is coming from your “catch” block where you are accessing error.response.data.  If error is an Error object then it will have a message property but not a response property.  You need to fix this to handle multiple types of errors (axios errors and standard Error objects).  You cannot rely on error.response always existing.

Comment: still the problem persists even I have change how I handle the errors. I created the same project using Context API. Still I encountered the same problem. Using [ContextAPI](https://github.com/lalapolalaanewb/testProj_contextApiVer1). Using [Redux Saga](https://github.com/lalapolalaanewb/testProj_redux). Seriously I'm at loss, I don't know where should I try to tweak next since the problem doesn't give me any different clue anymore.